# I want to replace multiple files Text with SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, text-processing

I want to replace multiple files with SSH.

I want to find all files with this pattern: `/home/*/public_html/wp-config.php`

And want to replace this line: `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

with:

`define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');`

Can someone tell me how this can be done?

Comment: why do you want (or think you need) to do this with SSH?

Comment: Thanks all, I just got this done:

find /home/*/public_html/wp-config.php -exec sed -i "s/define('WP_DEBUG', false);/define('WP_DEBUG', false); define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');/g" {} \;

All wp-cron.php on the server using massive CPU Usage on the node. Just need to disable it.

Comment: feel free to clarify MikeA's question about the focus on ssh (maybe you're just ssh'd to some host?) and to write your solution up as an Answer

Comment: @MikeA Probably because those files are on another machine, haha.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using *here-doc* to get ride of quoting conflicts (difficult to pass this as ssh argument without *here-doc*):

```
ssh host<<EOF
find /home/*/public_html/wp-config.php -exec sed -i "s/define('WP_DEBUG', false);/define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', 'true');/g" {} \
EOF
```

Doesn't take care of commented occurrences, modify a bit if needed.